# Detached Garage additional wiring

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel, garage, detached-structure

Hi I have a 1950s house in Indiana that has the original wiring to a detached garage. The garage is about 25-30 feet from the main panel. It currently only has a switch for the light.

I am planning to run a welder, and air compressor at some point so I would like to install a 110v and maybe a 220V  since I am going to run the wiring.

Should I run a subpanel to the garage or can I run two dedicated circuit arms to the garage with a shutoff in the garage?

Any other suggestions are appreciated. Here is a picture of my main panel.
[image][image]

Comment: That's the only panel you have? If so, you only have a 100 amp service?

Comment: Ya thats the only panel I have.

Comment: Not an original panel, somebody upgraded sometime recently since Eaton bought out BRyant/Cutler Hammer.   Wish they would've gone larger, is all.  But definitely, slap a 50A 2-pole BR in any 2 locations, run some #6 and off  you go.  A panel about this size would be just right for the subpanel.

Comment: Harper this should be an answer.+

Comment: So would I run a 6/3 UF-B WG?  And 1 or 2 ground rods? 4 ft or 8ft?

Answer (score 2):

You could do either, as your main panel seems to have capacity for both a double-pole breaker (240V) and a single-pole.

Adding a sub-panel in the garage would give you more flexibility both for adding things to the garage and by taking up less space in the main panel (2 spots vs. 3). So that would be my preference although it might be a little more expensive up front.